# Oracle to MySQL Migration : No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am migrating oracle database to mysql . I have an issue in date column. 
    Oracle has column name CREATED_DATE with data type DATE and store values as **"1/1/1981 2:04:35 PM"**

Java class code as

```
    class User{    
        @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")

       private Date createdDate; //java.utill.Date

     }
```

Now i am migrating oracle database to MySQL and create column  name CREATED_DATE with data type DATETIME in MySQL . I use same java class to connect database. But i got this error

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 

Can any one help me solve this issue? What will it take in mysql database to store same date format  **"1/1/1981 2:04:35 PM"**?
```

I use this javax.persistence file configuration . I used second level cache and mysql database .I can not find out what is the exact issue with it. Please suggest me how I can resolve this issue. Problem may be in mysql database column or hibernate configuration .

```
<properties>
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
             <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
                <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20"/>
                <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
                <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            </properties>
```

I have used many times `java.util.Date` data type in hibernate but i found this issue first time. So please help me how i can resolve this problem.

Comment: try with @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

Comment: @Apostolos It is not working for me

Comment: what exactly are you doing at the point of the exception? do you perform an hql query? can you post it here?

Comment: I just run my project .

Comment: @Entity
@NamedQueries({
 @NamedQuery(name = "User.getAllStoreItemLedgerDetailsBasedOnSILId", query = "SELECT s FROM StoreItemLedgerDetails s WHERE s.silId = :silId ORDER BY s.sildId DESC")
})

Comment: weird. i've never had problems when i declared Date and Timestamp fields with Temporal annotation.

Comment: @Apostolos Can you share what is data type of  java class and mysql column .

Comment: havent used mysql for years actually but for same sql types (date, timestamp or datetime) @Temporal(TemporalType.xxxxx) works fine. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html

Comment: Are you using `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: in comments he has util.Date so i guessed that this is the object he uses

Comment: @Apostolos i have added persistence file code in question please check this.

Comment: can you try with MySQL5Dialect? just a thought.

Comment: It is also not working .